# Restringir un input HTML a un número múltiplo de 0.05

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Quiero hacer un input con HTML para introducir la cantidad de metros que quiere comprar el cliente.

Dicha cantidad funciona de la siguiente manera:

- Cuando el cliente aprieta el botón <kbd>+</kbd> la cantidad se incrementa en `0,05`.
- Cuando el cliente aprieta el botón <kbd>-</kbd> se decrementa hasta llegar al mínimo de `0,30`.

Pero a parte de los botones, que ya funcionan, quiero dar la oportunidad al cliente de escribir directamente la cantidad que desea comprar. Eso sí, dicha cantidad debe ser múltiplo de `0,05`. Es decir, el cliente no puede introducir la cantidad `0,32`. En ese caso, quiero que el `input` se muestre en rojo y devuelva el error.

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo controlar ese `<input>`?

```js
$('.btn-plus, .btn-minus').on('click', function(e) {
  const isNegative = $(e.target).closest('.btn-minus').is('.btn-minus');
  const input = $(e.target).closest('.input-qty').find('input');
  if (input.is('input')) {
    input[0][isNegative ? 'stepDown' : 'stepUp']()
  }
});
```

```css
.product_single_quantity{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 18px;
}

.quantity-input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}

.quantity-input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
}

.btn-quantity {
    background-color: #03CF98;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
.form-control[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, .form-control[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9d1c67e670.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="product_single_quantity input-qty mt-20">
    <button class="btn-quantity btn-minus">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
    <input class="quantity-input quantity" name="quantity" value="0.30" min="0.30" step="0.05" type="number">
    <button class="btn-quantity btn-plus">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes? Agrega a la pregunta un fragmento de código con un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable pulsando en [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Validar un Input si es múltiplo de 0.05**

Hola, espero que el siguiente código le sea de utilidad. Para realizar la validación, debe asegurarse que el numero que ingrese el usuario sea múltiplo de 0.05. Esto se puede hacer aprovechando el residuo que genere la división del numero que ingrese en el input y el 0.05 así: `Numero % 0.05`. Ahora encontramos la relación algebraica de estos números y notamos que el resultado siempre será: 0.05 o 0. Ahora al saber este resultado podemos estar seguro que cualquier numero que de cualquiera de estos dos resultados será múltiplo de 0.05, por lo tanto podemos generar la siguiente lógica: `Numero === 0.05 || Numero === 0` será true en múltiplos de 0.05 y false si no es.

Aprovechando esta respuesta en valor booleano, puede crear un evento que muestre un mensaje de error al usuario. Aquí el ejemplo:

```js
$('.btn-plus, .btn-minus').on('click', function(e) {
  const isNegative = $(e.target).closest('.btn-minus').is('.btn-minus');
  const input = $(e.target).closest('.input-qty').find('input');
  if (input.is('input')) {
    input[0][isNegative ? 'stepDown' : 'stepUp']()
  }
});

//Funcion para saber si un numero es multiplo de 5
function SaberMultiple(numero){
  let resultado= numero % 0.05;
    resultado= parseFloat( resultado.toFixed(5) ); //Redondeando el risiduo
            if( ( resultado === 0.05000 || resultado === 0 ) && ( numero > 0.29 ) ){ return true}else{ return false}
}

//Funcion de validacion
function valida(e){
    let validacion= SaberMultiple(e.value);
  console.log( validacion )
        if(!validacion){ 
                    e.style= "border: solid 2px red;color:red;outline:none;"
                }else{
                            e.style="";
                        }
}

//evento de validacion cuando el usuario escriba en el input

let input= document.getElementById("entrada");

input.addEventListener("keyup",function(){ valida(this)   })

input.addEventListener("change",function(){ valida(this)   })

document.getElementById("menos").addEventListener("click",function(){ valida(input)   })

document.getElementById("mas").addEventListener("click",function(){ valida(input)   })
```

```css
.product_single_quantity{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 18px;
}

.quantity-input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}

.quantity-input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
}

.btn-quantity {
    background-color: #03CF98;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
.form-control[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, .form-control[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9d1c67e670.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="product_single_quantity input-qty mt-20">
    <button id="menos" class="btn-quantity btn-minus">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
    <input id="entrada" class="quantity-input quantity" name="quantity" value="0.30" min="0.30" step="0.05" type="number">
    <button id="mas" class="btn-quantity btn-plus">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

La solución más sencilla es dejar que CSS se haga cargo de detectar que el formulario es inválido (mediante el selector [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)) y mostrar en ese caso el borde rojo y un fondo rosado (para que se vea un cambio en el control cuando el foco esté en él y el borde decorado aún no sea visible):

```
/* Estilo cuando el control es inválido */
input:invalid {
  background-color: pink;
  border-color: red;
}
```

Adicionalmente podríamos controlar la pérdida del foco del control (mediante el evento [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)) para realizar un redondeo a la baja simulando la pulsación de una subida y, posteriormente, una bajada del valor:

```
/* Al perder el foco realizamos un redondeo a la baja */
$('input[step]').on('blur', function(e) {
  e.target.stepUp();
  e.target.stepDown();
});
```

O un redondeo más cercano al real usando el mismo método:

```
/* Al perder el foco realizamos un redondeo real */
$('input[step]').on('blur', function(e) {
  e.target.value = parseFloat(e.target.step) / 2 + parseFloat(e.target.value);
  e.target.stepUp();
  e.target.stepDown();
});
```

Para ello agrego la mitad del tamaño de un paso al valor actual y realizo el mismo redondeo a la baja anterior, dando como resultado un redondeo real.

No realizo el cálculo mediante `Math.round()` porque existen combinaciones en las que el resultado no es el número esperado (contiene un mayor número de decimales por el redondeo del número en coma flotante). Por ejemplo:

```
Math.round(0.37 / 0.05) * 0.05
0.35000000000000003
```

Aquí tienes tu código funcionando con ambas sugerencias:

```js
$('.btn-plus, .btn-minus').on('click', function(e) {
  const isNegative = $(e.target).closest('.btn-minus').is('.btn-minus');
  const input = $(e.target).closest('.input-qty').find('input');
  if (input.is('input')) {
    input[0][isNegative ? 'stepDown' : 'stepUp']()
  }
});

/* Al perder el foco realizamos un redondeo real */
$('input[step]').on('blur', function(e) {
  e.target.value = parseFloat(e.target.step) / 2 + parseFloat(e.target.value);
  e.target.stepUp();
  e.target.stepDown();
});
```

```css
.product_single_quantity{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 18px;
}

.quantity-input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}

.quantity-input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
}

.btn-quantity {
    background-color: #03CF98;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 42px;
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
.form-control[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, .form-control[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Estilo cuando el control es inválido */
input:invalid {
  background-color: pink;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9d1c67e670.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="product_single_quantity input-qty mt-20">
    <button class="btn-quantity btn-minus">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
    <input class="quantity-input quantity" name="quantity" value="0.30" min="0.30" step="0.05" type="number">
    <button class="btn-quantity btn-plus">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```